# ssh to remote machine via proxy server to run a script with parameters

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

I want to ssh to a machine via proxy server and run a script on that server with the inputs as parameters passed

I am using below :

```
ssh -t tooladm@200.81.36.188 "ssh -t tooladm@apuatt01" ". ./.profile >/dev/null 2>&1; cd /astxpinfs/ast/tooladm/JHF_SYNC_Particular_HF ; ./SyncToSite.ksh $product $release "${hf_list}" ${LOG_DIR_NAME} 2>&1 > /dev/null"
```

For clearance :

Suppose I am in machine A, and want to run the script located in machine apuatt01 
There is no direct connectivity b/w machine A and apuatt01
So I am connecting apuatt01 via 200.81.36.188

By using this, I am not able to run the above script

Please can you help, where I am doing wrong

Comment: no 200.81.36.188 is the intermediate machine .. apuatt01 is the destination machine, where the script is located

Comment: Please update the question with the error you got.

Comment: no error, but script at destination server is not running

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Bash here document](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) to make the script cleaner:

```bash
ssh -t tooladm@200.81.36.188 -- ssh -t tooladm@apuatt01 <<EOS
source .profile >/dev/null 2>&1
cd /astxpinfs/ast/tooladm/JHF_SYNC_Particular_HF
./SyncToSite.ksh $product $release "${hf_list}" ${LOG_DIR_NAME} 2>&1 > /dev/null
EOS
```

Note, the double dash separates the command from arguments passed to `ssh`.

This syntax works in `ksh`, too. From the KornShell manual(`man ksh`):

> `<<[-]word`     The shell input is read up to a line that is the same
>   as word after any quoting has been removed, or  to an  end-of-file.
>   No parameter substitution, command substitution, arithmetic
>   substitution or file name generation is performed on word.  The
>   resulting document, called a here-document, becomes  the  standard
>   input.   If any character of word is quoted, then no interpretation is
>   placed upon the characters of the document; otherwise, parameter
>   expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic substitution occur,
>   \new- line  is  ignored, and \ must be used to quote the characters \,
>   $, `.  If - is appended to <<, then all leading tabs are stripped from
>   word and from the document.  If # is appended to <<, then leading 
>   spaces and tabs will be stripped off the first line of the document
>   and up to an equivalent indentation will be stripped from the
>   remaining lines and from word.  A tab stop is assumed to occur at
>   every 8 columns  for the purposes of determining the indentation.

Comment: I need to use only ksh here :(

Comment: @user3426197, I can't help until I know what exactly is not working. Maybe remove redirection to `/dev/null` to look at possible error messages